# Algorithm to pass through all the connected points once for each collection of connected points

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

I'm trying to go through each "special" point in a 2D array once, I made a recursive function but it passes through several points multiple times, thus making the collection of special points much bigger than it should be.

```
void foo(int x, int y) {
    if( Board(x,y) == '*' ) {
        Point newpoint(x, y, '*');
        dq.push_back(newpoint);
        foo(x, ++y);//down
        //foo(x, --y);//up, disabled up to avoid infinite loops
        foo(++x, y);//right
        foo(--x, y);//left
    }
}
```

For example this could be the board, foo will receive the top left asterisk's location.

```
   asdf
      ****
       *****
    ****   ***
  4578       *   76767
```

Is this a known problem? Does it have a name that I could search for it?

PS: I know I can linearly go through each row, adding to the collection if the condition is true, but my end goal is to make several collections of connected asterisks and it's unknown how many collections there should be.

Comment: Flood fill?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dynamic programming: store the board coordinates that were already passed through as a `bool` 2D array (non-local to `foo()` or `static` in `foo()`), then mark each one as passed whenever you pass through it. Then invoke the recursion only if `passed[i][j]` is `false`.

Here is a brief tutorial to get you started with dynamic programming, that uses the typical example of recursive Fibonacci (which of course scales super badly if you don't use caching, i.e. dynamic programming):

http://functionspace.com/articles/32/Fibonacci-series-and-Dynamic-programming

Comment: Oh I like that idea! very nice.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you could use a series of breadth-first searches to find the regions of connected asterisks.  You could modify the original array or a copy of that array as you go to mark which coordinates have already been visited, or if the proportion of asterisks is small relative to the overall board then it might be more efficient to store the visited coordinate pairs in a hash table.